# Using java code how to extract text from single quotes. Also a specific instance

Tags: java, text, extract, quotes

I need to extract the third instance of text between single quotes using Java code.

Input text is:   'a','b','c'
Output text should be:    c

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I used this snippet of code that i borrowed from another post here:  
String mydata = "some string with 'the data i want' inside"; Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'"); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata); 
if (matcher.find()) { System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); } 

but it only shows the first instance of single quotes and the output is: a 

but i need the third instance.

Comment: if you wanted to use that matcher, you would have to grab a different group in System.out.println(matcher.group(n));

Answer (score 0):

you could do something simple and first split on the comma character from your string. `myString.split(",")`

This will supply you with an array containing ['a','b','c']   `array[0] = 'a', array[1] = 'b'....`

with then you can grab the third item or `array[2]` which will give you 'c'

You could then do a `charAt(1)` to retrieve this item. or if the item between the quotes is text, you could use substring to retrieve the item from the string.

So for `array[2] = "'bleh'"`  you could use `array[2].substring(1,array[2].length - 2);` Just make sure to do validation as this could easily cause index out of range exceptions.

an example of this would be:

```
public String getThirdVal(String input)
{
    String[] myArray = input.split(',');
    String wantedValue = myArray[2].substring(1, myArray[2].length - 2);
    return wantedValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. what package should i add to be able to use the split and substring methods?